# How to hide or close extra folder icons of the project view in QtCreator?

Tags: qt-creator

On my new laptop's QtCreator, why it showed extra folder icons? How to hide them? It really occupied and wasted my sidebar space.

Thanks so much : )

I tried to ask GPT and did some searches on Google, but nothing related was found. Neither is in the `option` menu. Hope there's one thing for all solutions.

screenshots : https://i.stack.imgur.com/np4Fe.png